# Why is c-lightning working when launched manually, but fails to start via systemd?

Tags: raspberry-pi, systemd, raspberry-pi-zero, lightning-network

I am trying to get a pruned c-lightning to launch on boot on a Raspberry Pi Zero W. It works when launched manually (which is great!) but not via systemd. I have tried many variations on the lightning.service file, but none of them have worked. It says "inactive (dead)" when I check the status, and if I do "sudo systemctl start lightning" it just hangs and the status remains "inactive (dead)".

Here is the simplest lightning.service file which ought to work (but doesn't):

```
[Unit]
Description=lightning-deamon
After=bitcoin.service
Requires=bitcoin.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/lightningd
User=doge
Group=doge
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
TimeoutStartSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Has anyone gotten this to work? Could you please post your lightning.service file? Any other ideas on why this might be failing?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working: bitcoind was being launched as 'forking' instead of 'simple', so it was never returning and so lightningd was never being called.